# Having issues with SQL Server self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000, rank

i have the following :

```
 USE xxx
 GO

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO

  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO

 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[branches](
     [branchNumber] [int] NULL,
     [isSub] [char](1) NULL,
     [masterBranch] [int] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

insert into branches 
values ( 115, 'Y', 900 ) 


insert into branches 
values ( 123, 'Y', 900 ) 

insert into branches 
values ( 150, 'Y', 900 ) 

insert into branches 
values ( 900, 'N', null ) 

insert into branches 
values ( 901, 'N', null ) 
 go
```

I need to check
a) Is 115 a isSub = Y? If it is, then I am done return 115.
b) Is 900 a IsSub = Y? If not, I need to return : 115, 123, 150, 900.
c) is 901 a isSub = Y? If not, I need to return 901.

It has been quite sometime since I looked at rank() function so I am kind of stuck at the moment. Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Is this for any specific version of SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple union seems to work.

```
select distinct branchNumber as num from dbo.branches
where branchNumber = 900
union
select branchNumber as num from dbo.branches
where masterBranch = 900
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, explicit `distinct` is superfluous when using `union`: the latter implies the former.

Answer (score 1):

So the first part (points A and C are identical here) of what you want to know is "Is this node a subordinate of something else?" That part is simple enough as you have already defined it in your DDL.

```
SELECT isSub FROM Branches WHERE branchNumber = @branchNumber
```

The second part is the "get all of the subordinates of this".

If you had SQL 2005+ This would involve [recursive common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (CTEs). This allows you to handle the kind of parent/child relationship you have listed there. The examples should guide you correctly if you can discount the JOINS (they are extra noise compared to your less complex need).

As you are working with SQL 2000, you are faced with a less elegant solution (of which there are a few).

- [This one](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm) that uses SProc recursion but is limited to 32 levels.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1781729/16391) that uses a UDF in similar fashion
- [This one](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q248915) that uses evil RBAR
- ...and a host of others if you search for "SQL 2000
  Recursive Queries"

If the first part is true, then execute the second and get the results.

I would recommend that you make these separate stored procedures or SQL calls. Having multiple structural variations of the return value of a stored proc can be problematic to maintain.